# Java Threads and Garbage Collection

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have read in countless places that running threads are garbage collection roots (ie they reside on the stack, the GC identifies them and traces through them to determine if the objects inside them are still reachable). Further more, a GC root will never be garbage collected itself.

My confusion is here: If the objects allocated from within a thread can never be garbage collected until the thread is stopped, how then is anything garbage collected in single-threaded programs where the only thread is the main thread ?

Clearly I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a thread (stack) is only a GC root while it is alive.  When the thread terminates, it is no longer a GC root.

> My confusion is here: If the objects allocated from within a thread can never be garbage collected until the thread is stopped, how then is anything garbage collected in single-threaded programs where the only thread is the main thread ?

Your premise is incorrect.

It doesn't matter which thread *allocates* an object.  What matters is whether an objects allocated by your thread *remains reachable*.    If it become unreachable (for example, if you didn't put the object's reference into a local variable) ... then it can be collected.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are in the heap, regardless which thread created them.

Objects may be reachable through *references*. Some of these references can be on the call stack of one or more threads.

An object can be collected when there are no more references to it, regardless whether is allocating thread is still running or not.

For example, the thread below repeatedly allocates new StringBuilder objects. During a call to foo(), the thread has references on its call stack to a StringBuilder object. When `foo()` returns, there are no further references to the StringBuilder object. Therefore, that object is no longer reachable, and is *eligible* for garbage collection.

```
Thread thread = new Thread( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( true ) {
            foo();
        }
    }

    public void foo() {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("This new object is allocated on the heap.");
        System.out.println( strBuilder );
    }
});

thread.run();
```

Comment: Given the code `void foo() {Widget temp = new Widget(); temp.DoSomething(); LongRunningMethod();}` is `temp` guaranteed to be considered a rooted reference during the execution of `LongRunningMethod`, even though it will never be referenced?  If not, is there an equivalent of the .NET `GC.KeepAlive(Object)` method which could be run after `LongRunningMethod` to ensure that `temp` cannot be forgotten before that?

Comment: Don't know. The reference is on the stack, and the stack frame is popped when the method returns, but I don't know if compiler optimization would be allowed to free the local reference after its last use in the method. That said, usually with GUI components, you're passing the component on to a toolkit that keeps its own reference.